# Flink Watermarking global?

Tags: apache-flink

Supposse I have two different datastreams, using event time.

```
class TSWM implements AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<POJO> {
   long maxTS = Long.MIN_VALUE;
   @Override
  public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(POJO event, long l) {
    maxTS = Math.max(maxTS, event.TS);
    return new Watermark(getMaxTimestamp());
  }

  @Override
  public long extractTimestamp(POJO event, long l) {
    maxTS = Math.max(maxTS, event.TS);
    return event.TS;
  }
}
```

`DataStream<POJO> ds1 = ... .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TSWM())`

`DataStream<POJO> ds2 = ... .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TSWM())`

So now I have two different datastreams, my question is, are the timestamps and watermarks seperate to **each datastream** or is it a centralized clock?

I am doing some other complex windowing and re-assignment of timestamps and watermarks and its not producing windowed data so I have a feeling the watermarking or timestamps is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watermarks are, in a sense, "global," but with the following caveats:

1. each parallel instance of assignTimestampsAndWatermarks does its own watermarking
2. when an operator connects two streams (e.g., a CoProcessFunction), its watermark is the minimum of the incoming watermarks
3. with Kafka you can arrange for per-kafka-partition watermarking

Comment: Thanks -- so in my example, `ds1, ds2` when i window each of them SEPERATELY, what exactly happens? if for example `ds1` is ahead of `ds2` at any point in time, do windows from `ds2` end up getting triggered?

Comment: If the streams are completely disjoint, then no. I suggest you bring up the Flink WebUI and look at the watermarks there. Or set some breakpoints in your IDE and debug what's going on.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for letting me know. How about re-assigning timestamps and watermarks. How does that work in a stream?

Comment: Is there any difference if I used an `AscendingTimespamtExtractor` thats provided with flink? The data I get from kafka is in sorted (By timestamp)order.

Comment: If you do a keyBy, that will shuffle the stream and can create out-of-orderness. As for re-assigning timestamps and watermarks, I'm not sure if that is well-defined, but my expectation is that this will override any previous timestamps and watermarks.

Comment: Thanks David! I'm in a bit of a tough situation in that case. What my application does it, read a Datastream from a kafka source convert it to a table then using Table API/SQL into 2 different datastreams. Now I assign each of them timestamps and watermarks and want to window. What I am wondering by your `disjoint` comment is, what exactly do you mean by that?  What is disjoint and how does it affect windowing?

Comment: If you connect two streams together, then their watermarks will mingle, but that can't cause windows to fire early -- instead, the stream that's behind can hold back the other. However, it doesn't sound like that's what's happening at all. It sounds like you are forking a stream (not merging them), and you are assigning timestamps and watermarks separately to the two sides of the fork.

Comment: This sort of back and forth discussion doesn't work well on stack overflow. I suggest you ask for help on the flink user mailing list.

Comment: Hi @David, I had just a last doubt about the concept as a whole wondering if you could answer. You said Watermarks are in a sense global -- If I am assigning timestamps and watermarks to 2 different streams and completely processing (keying windowing applying etc) them seperately (But within the same flink job), are the timestamps and watermarks and event time progression completely seperated between the two datastreams?

Comment: Yes, independent pipelines that happen to be running in the same job will not share timestamps or watermarks.

Comment: Thanks David! I owe you one